# Swift: @State property not updating on change

Tags: swift, swiftui

Every time I press the button an instance of the School struct is created. I want to show that change on the screen but the button doesn't update. What am I missing to make it work?

```
import SwiftUI

struct School {
    static var studentCount = 0

    static func add(student: String) {
        print("\(student) joined the school.")
        studentCount += 1
    }
}


struct ReviewClosuresAndStructs: View {
    
    @State private var test = School.studentCount
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                School.add(student: "Tyler")
            }, label: {
                Text("Press me. \n Students: \(test)")
            })
            
            
        }
    }
}


struct ReviewClosuresAndStructs_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReviewClosuresAndStructs()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why it should.

Comment: "Every time I press the button an instance of the School struct is created"... In fact, no instance of `School` was ever created since you've defined both `var` and the function as `static` (they're 'attached' to the `School` type, not a specific instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
struct School {
    var studentCount = 0 // <= here
    
    mutating func add(student: String) { // <= here
        print("\(student) joined the school.")
        studentCount += 1
    }
}


struct ReviewClosuresAndStructs: View {
    
    @State private var test = School() // <= here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                test.add(student: "Tyler")
            }, label: {
                Text("Press me. \n Students: \(test.studentCount)") // <= here
            })
        }
    }
}
```